# Default 404 page not working

Tags: 8

In a Drupal `8.5.3` installation I have set up the following configuration:

- I created a basic page, its node path is `/node/42`.
- Under *Administration » Configuration » System » Basic site settings* (`/admin/config/system/site-information`) I have set the **Default 404 (not found) page** to `/node/42`.

Now I expect a non-sensical URL to show the contents of `/node/42` for the 404 page. However, I still only get the generic 404 page.

The theme we are using does not have a custom 404 template or anything like that. What other reasons could there be, that the default 404 page is not the one set in the config?

Comment: did you try flushing the cache? Do you have another module handling 404 pages?

Comment: Yes, I executed `drush cr`. As far as I know there are no other modules handling 404 pages but I'll try to check if there could be one.

Comment: I'm also facing the same kind of issue in D8 - Its a multi domain site.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the multi-domain setup. I did not realize that you can/have to assign a different 404 page for each domain.